# How to detect when pdf is loaded in iframe when browser requests partial content range requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, iframe

I want to detect when a pdf has loaded, but the jQuery `.load()` event never fires when the browser requests the pdfs with partial content range requests in Chrome 40.

I want to trigger the browser print() function once the pdf has loaded. If the pdf is small enough the browser doesn't request ranges, but for larger pdfs how can I detect the pdf loading?

```
function download(src){

    var iframe;

    function check() {
        console.log('checking..');
        if(iframe.contentWindow && iframe.contentWindow.document && iframe.contentWindow.document.body && iframe.contentWindow.document.body.children && iframe.contentWindow.document.body.children.length > 0){
            console.log('embed element exists... how do I tell when it\'s loaded?');
        } else {
            timeout = setTimeout(check, 150);
        }
    }

    var timeout = setTimeout(check, 150);
    iframe = $('<iframe type="application/pdf" src="'+src+'"></iframe>').appendTo(document.body).load(function() {
        console.log('iframe is loaded. This never happens when there are range requests');
    }).get(0);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    download('test.pdf');
});
```

An example can be seen at http://stringham.me/pdf.html

Answer (score 0):

This may sound like a stupid answer, but have you tried the onload html attribute?

Comment: The onload html behaves similar to jQuery's `.load()` event handler. They both fire if the browser does not do a multiple request-ranges to download the pdf.